# Confused about integral curves on differentiable manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

I am a little confused about integration of curves in manifolds. An element of a tangent bundle is a vector field called $X$, made of a set of vectors tangent to a point $p$. How can we find the curve passing through the point $p$ as an integral curve of vector field? On the one hand, $X$ gives us $\dot g =X(g)$ with $g(0)=p$, but isn't the integral curve of $X$ only related to the point $p$, because $X$ is only related to the point $p$, but $g$ passes through many points?

The Frobenius theorem talks about local integrability and collections of vector fields, which may solve this, but I don't understand in what way. Since I'm only starting out in this topic, I don't really understand what is the difference between this stuff and typical diff eqs stuff is.

Thanks for any help you can offer, including references or basic definitions that I may have confused.

Comment: No, an *element* of the tangent bundle is *not* a vector field. It is a single tangent vector. To get a vector field you need a local section of the tangent bundle. Finding an integral curve of a vector field *is* just (local) ODE, nothing to do with Frobenius, which deals with finding higher-dimensional submanifolds whose (higher-dimensional) tangent spaces are prescribed.

Comment: @TedShifrin this helps, so thank you. So $X$ is actually a section of the tangent bundle. Is there a notion of integral curves of sections and how they relate to the fact that the diff eq described is a long path on the manifold? It seems to me like you would need multiple sections at each point $p_1, p_2, \ldots p_n$, but then what good is the integral curve of a single section? On the other hand, this section would fully define the solution to a normal diff eq, so what am I missing?

Comment: There are local sections of the tangent bundle and also global ones, but solving the ODE is usually a local thing (and then you can wonder if your solution is defined for all time, etc.). You can think of solving $\dfrac{d\phi_t(x)}{dt} = X(\phi_t(x))$ (with $\phi_0(x)=x$) as a (locally-defined) curve on the manifold, although there are ways to think about solutions up on the tangent bundle as well. Start with the easier one first.

Comment: The picture I have in mind when I say the path $\phi$ uses multiple points and so an integral curve of one $X(p)$ (meaning the field "tangent" to a given point) is meaningless is basically the picture in this wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_connection. It sounds like you're saying that's the wrong way to think about it, and the diff eq we wrote is local to $X$? Ultimately I'm trying to square away what an integral curve is in the context of the tangent bundle

Comment: As I said, you need a vector field, not a fixed tangent vector. Even you referred to a vector field. It is not assigning a value at a single point. It is assigning values at every point of an open subset of your manifold, unless otherwise specified. This is why we talk about *local* and/or *global* sections of the tangent bundle.

Comment: Ok, I think the key misunderstanding is of what a section is. the image I have in my head is like the picture shown here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tangent+bundle, the thing they label $P_x$. That's not it is it? so then the tangent vector field can extend over multiple points because its not that thing